# How to delete all the nodes that less than value n in a link list?

Tags: linked-list

How to delete all the nodes that less than value n in a link list? Anyone can show me a algorithm of how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Traversing a linked list is easy. Removing items from a linked list is easy. Comparing a value with a constant is easy. So which part do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a Node type with a next and value field, and not sorted (pseudo code, pointers, references or whatever may be needed depending on the language)

```
first = deleteNodesLessThan(node, val)

   first = node
   curr = node
   prev = node

   while curr

      # item to remove - delete it and update lins to maintain first,prev,curr
      if curr.value  < val

         if tmp == first
           first = curr.next
           prev = first
         else
           prev.next = curr.next
         end         

         delete(curr) 

         curr = prev.next

     else
       # nothing to remove, update to next
       prev = curr
       curr = curr.next
     end     
  end

  return first
```